# column <column> does not exist (Django 1.8)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

I am trying to interact with the development server for my django project. However any page on the server returns the same error:

```
Exception Type: ProgrammingError

Exception Value: column myApp_verb.date does not exist
```

I had not recently added the field date to the model verb (it's been there for a while, and I'm not sure what caused this error to begin). My collaborators all have identical files on their local machines, and none of them are having any issues.

I have tried various things:

I have tried removing the date field (and all references to it). `makemigrations` did not detect any changes, and `migrate` failed with error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "date" does not exist`

I have tried renaming the field. Once again `makemigrations` did not detect any changes, and migrate failed with the same error as above.

I have tried deleting all of my migrations. This changed nothing.

I'm out of ideas at this point. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is the verb class, as requested. Its pretty simple:

```
class Verb(models.Model):
    english_gloss = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    first_person = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    second_person = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    third_person = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    fourth_person = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    transitivity = models.BooleanField()
    classifier = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    inner_lexical = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    outer_lexical = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    perfective = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    imperfective = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

Comment: You need to share some code to get some help.

Comment: Can I see the model for `verb`?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I've added it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still have no idea why this error began, but it appears that there was some sort of corruption in my database. I deactivated the db and started a new one, and everything works perfectly again.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a manual migration to fix the issue.

First comment out the coloumn(s) that are throwing the error.

Then write the manual migration. Usually something like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations, models    

class Migration(migrations.Migration):   

    dependencies = [
        ('my_field', 'last_migration_filename'), # no .py
    ]        

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='my_model',
            name='my_field',
            field=models.MyField(blank=True, null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Then run `python manage.py migrate`. It will create that/those field(s).

Afterwards, uncomment the fields that cause the errors.

Worked for me like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem. I wanted to add field "slug" to City model.

Error gone when I temporary commented line with select_related('city').

```
for location in Location.objects.filter().select_related('city'):
    cities[str(l.id)] = l.city.id
```

Stack trace pointed me on that peace of code:

```
File "/www/loorn/apps/users/widgets.py", line 69, in LocationSelect
    for location in Location.objects.filter().select_related('city'):
```

Answer (score 1):

Fully agree with Özer S.
Yes, this is the only solution to overcome this problem. Dear Django developers, why when trying to add a field to an existing table, Django suddenly responds that such a field does not exist? Of course it does not exist, so I'm trying to add it!

The same solution is for my case - add a field with a multiple choice:

1. This is what the added field in models.py looks like:

   ```
   TEMPLATE = (
     ('list', 'List'), ('table', 'Table')
   )
   template = models.CharField(
       'View template',
       choices=TEMPLATE,
       max_length=7,
       default='list'
   )
   ```
2. Create manually a migration file with the number following the previous migration. I add the "template" field to the "blogcategory" table in the "blog" application and my migration file is called "0005_template".
3. And this is the contents of the migration file (0005_template.py):

   ```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   from django.db import migrations, models

   class Migration(migrations.Migration):
   dependencies = [
       ('blog', '0004_auto_20170628_1533'),
   ]

   operations = [
       migrations.AddField(
           model_name='blogcategory',
           name='template',
           field=models.CharField(
               verbose_name='View template',
               choices=[('list', 'List'), ('table', 'Table')],
               max_length=7,
               default='list'
           ),
       ),
   ]
   ```
4. Next, comment on these lines in the model:

   ```
   TEMPLATE = (
     ('list', 'List'), ('table', 'Table')
   )
   template = models.CharField(
      'View template',
      choices=TEMPLATE,
      max_length=7,
      default='list'
   )
   ```
5. Then, do the application migration in the database:

   ```
   python manage.py migrate blog
   ```

   and get

   ```
   Operations to perform:
       Apply all migrations: blog
   Running migrations:
       Applying blog.0005_template... OK
   ```

As a result, the "template" field with the default "list" was added to all entries in the "blogcategory" table.

P.S. Do not forget to uncomment the field in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem. I fixed it by going to the Django migrations table in the database and locating the migration that was faulty. In my case, it was a fairly recent migration. I deleted that migration and the others following it. Then retried running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. This time both commands ran and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually get around this type of error by "tricking" django into thinking the column exists while generating the migration.

- create a new database column with the same name manually in your local db
- run `python manage.py makemigrations` to generate the correct migration
- delete the column you created earlier
- run `python manage.py migrate 'appname'` to create the new column

Answer (score 0):

in my case i got this error when i first used models.ForeignKey() then changed to OneToOneFielf(). I just dropped the database then created a brand new one, ran migrations and it worked